# RFECV for feature selection for LogisticRegression, AdaBoostClassifier, RandomForestClassifier is taking too long

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use RFECV for feature selection of different Machine learning algorithms and it is taking too long. The code is running for hours and not giving any output..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSs0a.png)

Here is my code:

```
# Feature selection by RFECV
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

estimator = AdaBoostClassifier(random_state=0)
selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5)
selector = selector.fit(features, popular)
selector.ranking_

#estimator_LR = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
estimator_LR = LogisticRegression(C=1.0, tol=0.01, random_state=0, max_iter=10000)
selector_LR = RFECV(estimator_LR, step=1, cv=5)
selector_LR = selector_LR.fit(features, popular)
selector_LR.ranking_

estimator_RF = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
selector_RF = RFECV(estimator_RF, step=1, cv=5)
selector_RF = selector_RF.fit(features, popular)
selector_RF.ranking_
```

I tried to run the code 1 line at a time and the code is stuck on selector.fit line for all three classifier.

```
selector_RF = selector_RF.fit(features, popular)
```

My Dataset consist of almost 35000 instances and 60 attributes.

Comment: You said your code is stuck so, what kind of error are you getting ?

Comment: I mean that the code is in running mode and not giving any output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make these changes to make RFECV faster:

```
selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5, n_jobs = -1)
```

and

```
estimator_RF = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0, n_jobs = -1)
```

and `max_iter = 10000` is too much so,

```
estimator_LR = LogisticRegression(C=1.0, tol=0.01, random_state=45, max_iter=100)
```

setting `n_jobs = -1` parameter will tell your model to use all of your cpu cores and hence make code run faster.